# Rank of a matrix is equal to the dimension of its range

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix with rank $p(A) = k$. I want to show that the range of $A$, denoted by $\text{ran}(A)$, is also $k$. For completeness, $\text{ran}(A) = \{Ax: x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\}$.

**My proof:** Without loss of generality, let us assume $A$ is on its echelon form. Let $y = Ax \in \text{ran}(A)$ be arbitrary. For each $i \in \{1,...,m\}$, the $i$-th entry of $y$ is given by the product of the $i$-th row of $A$ with the column matrix which represents the vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Because $p(A)=k$, $A$ has $m-k$ rows with all entries equal to zero, so $y$ have $m-k$ entries equal to zero. Moreover, because $y$ is arbitrary, we see that any $y \in \text{ran}(A)$ is an element of the vector subspace generated by those nonzero rows of $A$. Thus, any $y \in \text{ran}(A)$ must be an element of a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: What is your definition of the rank ? Is it the dimension of the space spanned by all the columns of the matrix ?

Comment: rank is the number of linearly independent rows or, equivalently, the number of nonzero rows.

Comment: This is not equivalent at all : if you take a square matrix with all entries equal to $1$, then the maximal number of linearly independant rows is $1$ (all the rows are equal), but there is no nonzero rows. The good definition of the rank is the first one. Maybe a good start should be to prove that the maximal number of linearly independant rows is equal to the maximal number of linearly independant colulns.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean the number of nonzero rows when the matrix is on its echelon form. I was implicitly assuming the matrix is in its echelon form in my proof. Should've mentioned it!